# Partially close a polymer paper-drawer-panel

Tags: polymer, sidebar, drawer

I am looking to create a partially collapsing drawer panel based on Google Polymer v1.0. An example can be drawn from the popular AdminLTE website theme found here: https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview

In this demo, when the hamburger button is pressed, the sidebar collapses to only show the menu item icons.

Has anyone already done this? Or can you think of how to easily modify the paper-drawer-panel to do this?

Answer (score 0):

CSS classes? set in the on-tap handler of the hamburger menu.